# DataGridView doesn't show data when imported

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gembox-spreadsheet

Behind code of aspx page,  I have a Datatable:

```
            Dim people As DataTable = New DataTable()

            people.Columns.Add("ID", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
            people.Columns.Add("FirstName", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
            people.Columns.Add("LastName", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))

            people.Rows.Add(10, "Merci", "Beaucoup")
```

and this the GridViewData: (Not asp:GridView)

```
        Dim gvPeople As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView = New DataGridView()


        gvPeople.AutoGenerateColumns = False

        'Set Columns Count
        gvPeople.ColumnCount = 3

        'Add Columns
        gvPeople.Columns(0).Name = "ID"
        gvPeople.Columns(0).HeaderText = "ID"
        gvPeople.Columns(0).DataPropertyName = "ID"

        gvPeople.Columns(1).Name = "FirstName"
        gvPeople.Columns(1).HeaderText = "FirstName"
        gvPeople.Columns(1).DataPropertyName = "FirstName"

        gvPeople.Columns(2).Name = "LastName"
        gvPeople.Columns(2).HeaderText = "LastName"
        gvPeople.Columns(2).DataPropertyName = "LastName"
```

Here I set the datasource of the DataGridView to the DataTable:

```
        gvPeople.DataSource = people
```

When I import the DataGridView into the Excel sheet using `Gembox.Spreadsheet`, it only shows me the headerText of the DataGridView without the data. 
This is the Import Code:

```
        DataGridViewConverter.ImportFromDataGridView(ws, gvPeople, New ImportFromDataGridViewOptions() With _
            {
               .ColumnHeaders = True,
               .StartRow = 8,
               .StartColumn = 0
             })
```

I tried multiple things such as:

- setting up the `.DataMember` to the DataTable name : `gvPeople.DataMember=people.TableName`
- `Refresh()`  or    `Update()` the DataGridView after assigning the `.Datasource`.

Note: This is not an `asp:GridView`, it's a `DataGridView` and it does not have a `DataBind()` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*if using `asp:GridView`, Just use the `databind` function*

```
gvPeople.DataSource = people
gvPeople.Databind()
```

*Note: It is not recommended to use a datagridView in a Web project this control is designed for winforms applications.*

*If using `windows.Forms.DataGridView`*

`DataGridView` must be added to a form controls collection to perform its layout

```
Me.Controls.Add(gvPeople)
```

But this cannot be done when using web project (Getting Error)

so you have to do some workaround

First i created a Function that convert a datarow to an array of string

```
Public Function ToStringArray(ByVal dRow As DataRow) As String()

    Dim lst As New List(Of Object)
    lst.AddRange(dRow.ItemArray)

    Return lst.Select(Function(x) x.ToString).ToArray()

End Function
```

Then i used the Following code

*this is your code:*

```
    Dim people As DataTable = New DataTable("people")

    people.Columns.Add("ID", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
    people.Columns.Add("FirstName", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
    people.Columns.Add("LastName", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))

    people.Rows.Add(10, "Merci", "Beaucoup")

    Dim gvPeople As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView()


    gvPeople.AutoGenerateColumns = False

    ''Set Columns Count
    gvPeople.ColumnCount = 3

    ''Add Columns
    gvPeople.Columns(0).Name = "ID"
    gvPeople.Columns(0).HeaderText = "ID"
    gvPeople.Columns(0).DataPropertyName = "ID"

    gvPeople.Columns(1).Name = "FirstName"
    gvPeople.Columns(1).HeaderText = "FirstName"
    gvPeople.Columns(1).DataPropertyName = "FirstName"

    gvPeople.Columns(2).Name = "LastName"
    gvPeople.Columns(2).HeaderText = "LastName"
    gvPeople.Columns(2).DataPropertyName = "LastName"
```

*And here is my Added Code*

```
    For Each drow As DataRow In people.Rows
        gvPeople.Rows.Add(ToStringArray(drow))
    Next

    gvPeople.RowCount = people.Rows.Count

    gvPeople.Refresh()
```

Comment: This is not a `asp:GridView`. this a `DataGridView` and it doesn't have a `Databind()` method

Comment: @Wafae the datagridview showed some data? Or the problem is only at the import process?

Comment: it does not show any data at all, It only shows the column headers. I am not sure what's causing the problem (the Import process or the DataGridView it self)

Comment: Why using datagridview instead of gridview in an asp.net project?

Comment: because I can't find a method that imports an` asp:gridView` using the `gembox.spreadsheet`, the only methods I found were for DataGridView or a DataTable, but not for a gridView

Comment: what is .StartRow = 8 there, I think it should be  0, if its what I think

Comment: @satsvelke `.StartRow` decides which row the DataGridView should be exported to in the Excel sheet. Even when it's set to 0 or not added at all, it doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: @Hadi Thank you for your efforts!

Answer (score 2):

You should really reconsider that approach (using DataGridView in ASP.NET application).

If you want to insert only a data from GridView control into an Excel file, then use DataTable.

As you mentioned in the comments, you want to customize which columns to export and the order of the columns. In that case, you just need to adjust the DataTable itself, for example try the following:

```
' Sample DataTable.
Dim people As New DataTable()

people.Columns.Add("ID", GetType(Integer))
people.Columns.Add("FirstName", GetType(String))
people.Columns.Add("LastName", GetType(String))

people.Rows.Add(1, "John", "Doe")
people.Rows.Add(2, "Jane", "Doe")
people.Rows.Add(10, "Merci", "Beaucoup")

' Remove "ID" column.
people.Columns.Remove("ID")

' Set "LastName" column on first place.
people.Columns("LastName").SetOrdinal(0)

' Create Excel file.
Dim ef As New ExcelFile()
Dim ws As ExcelWorksheet = ef.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1")

' Insert DataTable into Excel file.
Dim op As New InsertDataTableOptions()
op.ColumnHeaders = True
ws.InsertDataTable(people, op)

' Save Excel file.
ef.Save("Sample.xlsx")
```

I hope this helps.
Also just in case you're interested here is how you would insert the data together with the styling and formatting from the GridView control into an Excel file with GemBox.Spreadsheet:
https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/support-center/kb/articles/export-gridview-and-or-datagrid-control-to-excel-file

Comment: I agree, I have already reconsidered it. I was evaluating this product for Excel reports, and the option of customizing the DataTable itself is sometimes not available. Thank you for your input!

Comment: I'm not sure in which situations you'll not be able to customize DataTable, but in those cases maybe you could for example clone the DataTable and do the customization on the cloned version. Nevertheless you always have an option of using a straightforward approach in which you would just iterate through your data source (which can be of any type) by rows or by columns and you would read those data source values and set appropriate ExcelCell.Value with them.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using datagrid in asp.net application you can use asp gridview 
which is possible according below link

```
 https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/examples/asp-net-excel-export/5101
```

Comment: the example used in the link uses `InsertDataTable` method which Imports the DataTable, not the GridView. I want to insert/import the GridView into the excel sheet not the DataTable.

Comment: @Wafae if you can use the datatable why using the gridview?

Comment: @Hadi because I want to customize which columns to export and the order of the columns. I don't want to export the DataTable the way it is. Thats why I am using a grid, so I can customize which columns and the order of the columns exported.